# Socket.io connection detected on Python server but not triggering events in JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, python, html, socket.io

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to establish a connection between a Flask-SocketIO server in Python and an HTML page using JavaScript. On the Python side, I can see that the connection is successfully established. However, on the JavaScript side, I don't receive any events or logs indicating a successful connection.

Here is my code:

#### **server.py:**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask_cors import CORS
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64
import io

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

def get_screen():
    while True:
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        frame = np.array(screenshot)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        encoded_img = base64.b64encode(jpeg.tobytes())
        yield encoded_img

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    start_sending()

def start_sending(): 
    global stop_stream
    stop_stream = False
    while not stop_stream:
        for frame in get_screen():
            emit('image', frame.decode('utf-8'))
            socketio.sleep(0.1)  

@socketio.on_error_default 
def default_error_handler(e):
    print('An error occurred:', e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

#### **templates/index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Stream Viewer</title>  
            <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-c79GN5VsunZvi+Q/WObgk2in0CbZsHnjEqvFxC5DxHn9lTfNce2WW6h2pH6u/kF+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img id="screenFrame" style="max-width: 100%;">

            <script> 
                var socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

                socket.on('connect', function(){console.log('connect!')}); 
                socket.on('disconnect', function(){console.log('disconnect!')}); 

                socket.on('image', data => {
                    console.log("Image data received");
                    const img = document.getElementById('screenFrame');
                    img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: its `socket.on('connection', function(){console.log('connect!')});` not `connect`

Comment: bro read the documentation -> https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: Please stay calm. I already tried both and they do not work `bro`.

Comment: it seems to be working correctly, your issue seems to lie with `get_screen` this code is causing issues

Comment: This part is actually working fine for me. I tried replacing the `emit('image', frame.decode('utf-8'))` with `with open("test.jpg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(frame))` and it worked fine